# How to add text to a gif image? IOS

Tags: iphone, ios, ipad, png, gif

**I just have a "gif" image , and I want to send the gif image to some by email just as a card. Before sending the user can add words to the gif image. Help me and thanks.**

it was that:  add some words to the gif image. just as my title. at last i wanna get a gif form of image. xx.gif

Comment: Can you be more specific and improve your question?

Comment: just as my title. at last i wanna get a gif form of image. xx.gif

Comment: Although you use tags, it might be good to describe your platform and what restrictions you might have.

Answer (score 0):

You could use the netpbm tools to do this pretty easily. Generate an image of the same size as the GIF using pbmtext or GhostScript, and convert the GIF to ppm with giftopnm. Then, combine the two to produce a new image using pnmarith, pbmmask/pnmpaste, ppmmix, or similar. Then convert the result back to GIF with giftopnm.
[Edit] Sorry, I missed the iOS tag; I assumed the questioner wanted a server-side solution. Indeed, this approach wouldn't work on an iPhone.

Comment: Good luck doing this in an iPhone app. *I* would rather use Core Graphics, but that's my opinion.